Discord.pyでBotからファイルをアップロードすると、チャンネルで表示されるファイル名の半角英数以外の文字が消える
困りごと
Discord.pyのファイルアップロードの手順でファイルをアップすると、ファイル名に含まれる全角文字が消滅します。
半角の文字は表示されるため、全角文字をアップロード完了後に発言の再編集で日本語を挿入すれば解決するかもしれませんが、妥当なやり方とは思えないので別の解決方法をご存知でしたら教えてください。
スペック
・Windows 10から自分で新規開設したdiscordに接続
・Botの設定（web側で設定できる項目）はいったん全機能ＯＮにしてあります。（ＯＦＦでも再現性ありました）
・pythonスクリプトをＰＣローカルからコマンドプロンプトで実行
・Python         3.12.3
・pip discord    2. 3.2
・pip discord.py 2. 3.2
サンプルコード（私のやり方で再現性のある項目のみ抽出）
    import discord
    from discord.ext import commands
    import asyncio
    
    TOKEN = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA' # Botトークン
    OUTPUT_CHANNEL_ID = 0000000000000000000000000000 # チャンネルのID
    
    intents = discord.Intents.default()
    intents.messages = True
    
    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="", intents=intents)
    
    @bot.event
    async def on_message(message):
    
        # 指定チャンネルIDの部屋での任意の発言をトリガーとしてファイルをアップロート
        # ただし自身（BOT）の発言はカウントしない
        if message.channel.id == OUTPUT_CHANNEL_ID and not message.author.bot:
            output_ch = bot.get_channel( OUTPUT_CHANNEL_ID )
            await output_ch.send(file=discord.File( 'ファイルパス/あいうえおabc123漢字１２３.zip' ))
    
    bot.run(TOKEN)

実行結果
・理想：あいうえおabc123漢字１２３.zip
・現実：abc123.zip
備考
・とりあえずエラーコードは出ていない
・必要な要素があれば指摘してください。
提案内容組み込み 2024/05/20更新
kunifさんのコメントになったfpとfilenameの明示的な指定を行ってみました。
対象の修正箇所は以下の設定でテストしています。
# 修正前
await output_ch.send(file=discord.File( 'ファイルパス/あいうえおabc123漢字１２３.zip' ))
# 修正後
await output_ch.send(file=discord.File(fp='ファイルパス/あいうえおabc123漢字１２３.zip',filename='あいうえおabc123漢字１２３.zip'))

この書式仕様で実行しましたが、残念ながら改善は見られませんでした。
ただし、filenameに設定した内容がファイル名と異なっていてもアップロード処理に影響が無いようなので、任意でファイル名の見かけの値を変更することは可能だとわかりました。
コメントありがとうございました。
次点
discord.py内を調べていたところ、discord.Fileオブジェクトの変数値を以下の書式で取得できました。
file = discord.File(上述引数)
print(file.fp       ) # fp       の値
print(file._filename) # filename の値
print(file.spoiler  ) # spoiler  の値※ネタバレ対策非表示モードのbool

この時点では正常に値を保持していることがわかりました。
そのため、discord.pyがさらに参照している深層のライブラリか、discord側そのものの不具合ではないかと考えています。

もしかしたら、file=discord.File('ファイルパス/あいうえおabc123漢字１２３.zip')とした時にfpパラメータであるパス名だけではなく、明示的にfilenameパラメータも指定してみてはどうでしょう？ File, property filename Discordにアップロードするときに表示されるファイル名。指定されていない場合はデフォルトでは fp.name 、または fp が文字列の場合、 filename は与えられた文字列をデフォルトにします。 discord.pyでBotを作ったのでわかりやすく解説しようと思う。 [Part.3]

cubick様　いつも修正ご指摘ありがとうございます。
kunif様　いつもありがとうございます。いったん調べてみます。進展あれば追記させてもらいます。

原因が判明しました。
discordの仕様上、
添付ファイルアップロードの操作から日本語（全角文字全般だと思います）を含むファイルをアップロードすると自動的に日本語が消滅する不具合でした。
discord.pyは特に悪さはしておらず、本件の原因はdiscord側の仕様が問題であると判明しました。
お騒がせしました。お調べいただきありがとうございました。
これにてクローズします。

ここの説明のようですね。Uploading Files Images can also be referenced in embeds using the attachment://filename URL. The filename for these URLs must be ASCII alphanumeric with underscores, dashes, or dots.

kunif様　はい、一般の利用ユーザーの方から同様の不具合に関する言及をネットで見つけて解決に至りました。解決しないことが確定したことを解決と呼べればですが…。
